# BigQuery JSON Field Extraction

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following JSON payload stored in a single string column in a BQ table.

```
{
"customer" : "ABC Ltd",
"custom_fields" : [
     {
      "name" : "DOB",
      "value" : "2000-01-01"
     },
     {
      "name" : "Account_Open_Date",
      "value" : "2019-01-01"
     }
]
}
```

I am trying to figure out how I can extract the custom_fields name value pairs as columns?

Something like follows.

```
| Customer.name    | Customer.DOB    | Customer.Account_Open_Date |

| ABC Ltd          | 2000-01-01      | 2019-01-01                 |
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [json-functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#json-functions) , such as

```
JSON_EXTRACT(json_string_expr, json_path_string_literal)
```

In your case will be

```
SELECT 
JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.customer') as Customer.Name,
JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.custom_fields[0].value') as Customer.DOB,
JSON_EXTRACT(json_text, '$.custom_fields[1].value') as Customer.Account_Open_Date
```

Comment: I did look at this before, but i was looking at making this more generic by not hardcoding the column names. Is there anyway we can derive the column name based on the "name" field ?

Comment: You may try unset json array unest($.custom_fields[].value)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52120182/bigquery-json-extract-all-elements-from-an-array or you have to write some UDF.