# Bigquery - json_array extract and count elements from a nested arrays

Tags: sql, arrays, json, google-bigquery

I have a JSON field my table which looks like this. There could be any number of menu categories and any number of items

```
{
"menu": {
    "salad": [
        {
            "item": "russian salad"
        },
        {
            "item": "french salad"
        }
    ],
    "soups": [
        {
            "item": "french soup"
        },
        {
            "item": "english soup"
        },
        {
            "item": "english soup"
        }
    ]
}
```

There could be any number of menu category (salad, soup) plus any number of items within each category

```
salad | 2
soups | 3
```

I've looked at my [own previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66800828/bigquery-json-array-extra-multiple-elements-from-a-fields), but unsure how I can modify to accommodate for any number of categories and items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider below approach

```
select key, array_length(split(values)) items
from `project.dataset.table`,
unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_keys`(json_extract(col, '$.menu'))) key with offset 
join unnest(`bqutil.fn.json_extract_values`(json_extract(col, '$.menu'))) values with offset 
using(offset)
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

Comment: Thanks once again. Just to note for anyone else struggling with bgutil, it's not currently (Jan 2021) available outside the US as a public dataset, it needs to be deployed, https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/bigquery-utils/issues/252